# "Resource is currently edited in another editor" after saving ANTLR grammar file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, antlr4

I am using [antlr4ide](https://github.com/jknack/antlr4ide) plugin with Eclipse Luna. Every time I save the ANTLR4 grammar file Eclipse shows a dialog box "The resource is currently edited in another editor. Do you want to continue?"
Any hint on how to fix it?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I experienced the same behavior editing less files using an editor packed in a plugin. I opened the file with the eclipse standard text editor which do not suffer that problem. Maybe you want to give it a try because the dialog box appearing every time is very annoying.

Comment: I did that but I am losing syntax highlighting